# Does the intersection of two moving curves sweep out a continuous line?

Tags: geometry, curves, plane-geometry

Suppose we have two curves, $A$ and $B$.  The domain of $A$ is $D_x(A)=\{x_p|P\in A\}=(x_1;x_2),D_y(A)=\{y_p|P\in A\}=(y_1;y_2),\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\ll 1$.  Similarly, $D_x(B)=\{x_p|P\in B\}=(x_1;x_2),D_y(B)=\{y_p|P\in B\}=(y_1;y_2),\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}\ll 1$.  (Roughly, if you zoom far enough out, they form a cross).  Neither $A$ nor $B$ is required to be "nice" - they must merely be continuous, but it is not required that they be differentiable.

Then $A$ undergoes a continuous translation whose total length is much less than the length of either of the curves.  Let $S$ be the set of points which are in $A\cap B$ at any point during the translation.

Is it true that there is always a point $p_0\in A\cap B$ at time $t=0$ and a point $p_1\in A\cap B$ at time $t=T$ such that there is a connected component in $S$ which includes both points?  (The choice of points is made freely; only one such pair need exist)

It seems obvious to me that this is true, but I cannot prove it.  Given the difficulty of the Jordan Curve theorem (and my lack of a background in geometry), I don't expect it to be simple.  Apologies for any lack of rigor; I hope I've communicated it clearly.

Comment: The domain and co-domain of $A$ is $-N<x<N$ and $-M<y<M$. Do you mean that for any $x_1$ from domain there is point of $A$ that has $x=x_1$ and for any $y_1$ from co-domain there is point of $A$ that has $y=y_1$? Does curve $x^2+y^2=M^2/4$ allow your condition for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Hm.  No, that's not what I meant.  I meant that, roughly, $A$ is vertical and $B$ is horizontal and that they cross and do not uncross during the translation.  I'd appreciate a better way to describe that.

Comment: To say that $A$ is hotrizontal, you can write it so: $D_x(A)=\{x_P|P\in A\}=(x_1;x_2)$, $D_y(A)=\{y_P|P\in A\}=(y_1;y_2)$, $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\ll 1$. You can place arbitrary additionsl limitations on $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$, for example $-N < x_1 < -N/2 < N/2 < x_2 < N$, $-M < y_1 < -M/2 < M/2 < y_2 < M \ll N$.